# Remote OS detection with PHP

Tags: php

I run a Apache/php server on Mac, and I want to show different info based on the OS that accesses it.

How can I do that with PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user-agent header might reveal some OS information, but i wouldn't count on that.

For your use case i would do an ajax call using javascript from the client side to inform your server of the client's OS.

Here is an example.

Javascript (client side, browser detection + ajax call ):
(Note: You will need the [detection script from here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.htm))

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() { 
  if (BrowserDetect) { 
    var q_data = 'ajax=true&browser=' + BrowserDetect.browser + '&version=' + BrowserDetect.version + '&os=' + BrowserDetect.OS; 
    var query = 'record_browser.php' 
    var req = new Request.JSON({url: query, onComplete: setSelectWithJSON, data: q_data}).post(); 
  } 
});
```

PHP (server side):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
    $session = session_id(); 
    $user_id = isset($user_id) ? $user_id ? 0; 
    $browser = isset($_POST['browser']) ? $_POST['browser'] ? ''; 
    $version = isset($_POST['version']) ? $_POST['version'] ? ''; 
    $os = isset($_POST['os']) ? $_POST['os'] ? ''; 

    // now do here whatever you like with this information
}
```

Comment: +1 but it would have been nice to show a sample of the JS code to do that for non-expert :)

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the user-agent header ([`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)). For example, an iPhone user-agent looks like:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU **iPhone OS
>   3_0** like Mac OS X; en-us)
>   AppleWebKit/420.1 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Version/3.0 Mobile/1A542a Safari/419.3

An Windows XP one might look like:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; **Windows NT
>   5.1**; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10

And so on. See a simple script [here](http://www.geekpedia.com/code47_Detect-operating-system-from-user-agent-string.html). You can also use [`get_browser()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) (you'll need [browscap](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp) though)

Note that this header can easily be faked and thus shouldn't be used for anything mission critical.

Answer (score 1):

Reliably? You can't.

Unreliably? `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` often contains OS information.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getBrowser()
    {
        $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $bname = 'Unknown';
        $platform = 'Unknown';
        $version= "";

        //First get the platform?
        if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'linux';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'mac';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'windows';
        }

        // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
        if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
            $ub = "MSIE";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
            $ub = "Firefox";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Google Chrome';
            $ub = "Chrome";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Apple Safari';
            $ub = "Safari";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Opera';
            $ub = "Opera";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $bname = 'Netscape';
            $ub = "Netscape";
        }

        // finally get the correct version number
        $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
        $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
        ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
        if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
            // we have no matching number just continue
        }

        // see how many we have
        $i = count($matches['browser']);
        if ($i != 1) {
            //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
            //see if version is before or after the name
            if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
                $version= $matches['version'][0];
            }
            else {
                $version= $matches['version'][1];
            }
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }

        // check if we have a number
        if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

        return array(
            'userAgent' => $u_agent,
            'name'      => $bname,
            'version'   => $version,
            'platform'  => $platform,
            'pattern'    => $pattern
        );
    }

var_dump(getBrowser());
```

see details  [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

Answer (score 0):

[get_browser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function will parse $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] for you.  You need browsecap.ini though.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than implementing this yourself I'd try using an existing piece of software like [Browser.php](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/) that parses the user agent string for you. There's so many little things you need to take into account it's best to use a specialized library rather than trying to learn all these little platform/browser incongruities yourself.